# Are the upvotes and accepted marks keeping these bad answers from very-high-rep users alive?

Tags: discussion, answers, reputation

I [modified a SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/359551) posted [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/304195/what-is-the-average-vote-on-accepted-answers?cb=1#comment241961_304197) by Bill The Lizard to give the answer IDs of the lowest scoring accepted answers on Stack Overflow. The two worst answers, surprisingly come from [Darin Dimitrov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/29407/darin-dimitrov) (610k rep) and [CommonsWare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware) (496k rep):

1. 71 down, 11 up, **✓** (https://stackoverflow.com/a/4704901)
2. 68 down, 16 up, **✓** (https://stackoverflow.com/a/2836754)

Is it the upvotes and accepted marks which are keeping these answers alive? It surprises me that two users with a combined reputation of over 1 milli,ooo,ooon would want to keep these answers associated with their profiles.

Comment: I'm not sure if the upvotes make a difference, but AFAIK if the answer is accepted you can't deleted it, until OP unaccepts it. (Or you probably have to flag it for a mod if you want to remove it)

Comment: @Rizier123 that's interesting, I wasn't aware that accepted answers couldn't be deleted. Seems there's a [popular post here against that](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272849/please-allow-me-to-delete-my-own-accepted-answer).

Comment: @Rizier123 A mod will not remove those answers unless there are fundamental problems with it (like spam, plagiarism, etc.). Mods are exception handlers, they don't adjudicate on technical accuracy of answers.

Comment: The developers are working on a way to hide or deprecate outvoted, accepted answers: [@Tim Post♦ in Implement a vote-based warning system for potentially dangerous answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/298911/266143).

Comment: "It surprises me that two users with a combined reputation of over 1 milli,ooo,ooon would want to keep these answers associated with their profiles." -- Who can tell? What if they wanted to keep them around, as a reminder of human fallibility?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is *very* little that they can do about it.  Once a post is marked as the answer it cannot be deleted anymore.  Sometimes a moderator is sympathetic but that isn't very common.  The few times I tried it myself before giving up on it, they usually insisted on me editing the answer instead.  Not actually that easy to do without raising plagiarism hackles.  The one time it did work, that I can remember, a glut of very hateful comments probably helped.

You can help here, possibly better if it comes from somebody else.  Not actually sure.  Consider a "Please help this guy out of his misery" custom flag.

Comment: Actually, trusted users can delete-vote them, as they are below zero. So that's what I did. Needs two more votes each.

Comment: Good idea, I'll help.  James can finish it off.

Comment: High rep users who can delete posts can help people out of their misery by Review -> Tools > Lowest voted. Pick a time frame. Unfortunately it only works for the past 30 days.

Comment: and there is (are) no accepted answer(s) now.